# Unicode Kangxi radicals range 2F00–2FDF not displayed on iphone device, but in simulator

Tags: iphone, unicode

Kangxi radicals in the range 2F00-2FDF (see [link text](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2F00.pdf)) are not displayed correctly on the iPhone device. They appear as a crossed-out box. In the simulator they display correctly.

I tried the system font and also the

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiTC-Medium" size:24];
```

... Is the unicode codepoint coverage limited on the iphone (in my case OS 3.1.3)?

How to make those radicals appear???

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `HiraKakuProN-W3` (normal) or `HiraKakuProN-W6` (bold).